# ARCore How to replace the detected plane to custom 3d model in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm really new to the ArCore, can anyone guide me on how to replace or change the detected plane object to that model what I want to display.

What I'm trying to do is when the app is launched, we scan the ground and instead of a plane I want to show the shaded version of my model, and once I tap on the screen I want to place the actual model.

I'm trying to do this with UNITY in ARCore.

Reference images:

[image: Screenshot-01]

[image: Screenshot-02]

Can anyone help me with this?